# click not trigger on first row of tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have table like:

```
<table id="tlist" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspace="0">
    <thead><tr><th>sort</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="lrow"><td>first</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lrow"><td>second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lrow"><td>third</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want click the first row of tbody. I have tried some solutions.

What I have tried:

```
//$("#tlist tr").first().css("background-color", "#00f");
$("#tlist").find("tr").eq(1).addClass("highlight");
$("#tlist").find("tr").eq(1).trigger("click");

$(".lrow").click(function() {
    alert("c");
});

$("#tlist tr").on('click', function() {
    alert("d");
});
```

I run these code above on document ready using jquery. It not works. `highlight` was added to the target row. But the color not changed. I put it on [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppdouble/px4q78w9/2/).
Any one have some adives? Thanks for your time.

Comment: `.eq(1)` will be attached to second element, it's 0-based

Comment: 0 would be the row in thead. 1 would be first row of tbody for my table.

Comment: try as `$("#tlist > tr").eq(0).addClass("highlight");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the sequence, Bind event first then use trigger.

*Script*

```
//Even Binding
$(".lrow").click(function () {
    alert("c");
});

$("#tlist tr").on('click', function () {
    alert("d");
});

//Trigger event
$("#tlist").find("tr").eq(1).addClass("highlight");
$("#tlist").find("tr").eq(1).trigger("click");
```

Also in CSS,

```
.highlight{
    background-color: #0f0;  //remove quotes
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/0fss2a0f/)

Answer (score 2):

In your fiddle first include jquery library and look at below error in css

```
.highlight td{
    background-color: "#0f0";
}
```

change to this

```
.highlight td{
    background-color: #0f0;  // remove double quotes
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/px4q78w9/12/)

Comment: Welcome Dong Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$("#tlist").find("tr").eq(1).addClass("highlight");
$("#tlist").find("tr").eq(1).click(function(){
  alert();
});
```

CSS :

```
.highlight td{
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

OR

```
 $("#tlist tbody").find("tr").eq(0).addClass("highlight");
 $("#tlist tbody").find("tr").eq(0).click(function(){
  alert();
});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight td{
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

DEMO :- http://jsfiddle.net/d1mhdhzm/

Comment: Answer supported by Satpal can work. First, define click event action. Second, trigger the event. @Exception